# Accessing variable passed to callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

Can anyone explain why the following won't work? 
The setTimeout callback in watchLog() will output undefined.

```
function initWatchers() {
    if (config.watchLogs.length >= 1) {
        config.watchLogs.forEach(function(path) {
            watchLog(path);
        });
    }
}

function watchLog(path) {
    setTimeout(function(path) {
        console.log(path)
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `setTimeout`, when calling the callback function, does not pass any parameter into the function. So the parameter `path` in `function (path)` doesn't get any value and is `undefined`. Further, it shadows the `path` variable in the outer scope, replacing it (with `undefined`). You actually want this:

```
function watchLog(path) {
    setTimeout(function () {
    // no shadowing arg ^^
        console.log(path)
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Inner function's scope is it's parent function's context, so it can access the variable.